# Como eliminar al momento, elemento de una tabla

Tags: javascript, controller, table

Tengo una tabla la cual al final de cada fila tiene un boton para eliminar, este boton manda primeramente a una fucntion en js:

```
function Eliminar(id) {


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Home/Eliminar?id=' + id,
        dataType: "json",

        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function () {

        }
    });
}
```

Donde en el ajax va despues a una function en el controller, donde hace la eliminacion en la base de datos

```
public JsonResult Eliminar(string id)
        {
            var _id = id;
   
                using (var context = new BD())
                {
                    var _id_unidad = context.carros.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
                    context.carros.Remove(_id_carro);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }              
        }
```

En la eliminacion no hay ningun problema, lo hace correctamente, pero para poder ver los cambios es necesario recargar la pagina, y quisiera evitar eso, necesito que tambien al momento la fila desaparezca de la tabla, algun ejemplo de como le puedo hacer?

La tabla se llena como vista parcial:

html:

```
<div class="row">
     <center>
     <p style="color:#523e02; font-weight:bold; font-size:28px;">CARROS</p>
<div class="col-lg-12 ml-auto">
      div class="card shadow border-0">
          <div class="card-body">
           <div id="tabla_carros">Sin datos disponibles</div>
      </div>
        <div style="height:10px;background-color:#14497b;"></div>
        <div style="height:10px;background-color:#88c164;"></div>
     </div>
  </div>
</center>
</div>
```

Vista parcial:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}


<table id="tabla_principal_activas" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Unidad</th>
            <th>Numero</th>
            <th style="width:25%;">Acciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="carros">
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.carros)
        {

            <tr>
                <td>@item._unidad</td>
                <td>@item.numero</td>
                <td>                    
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" value="@item._idUnidad" onclick="Eliminar(this.value)"> X</button>

                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Adjunta como tienes la estructura HTML de tu tabla...

Comment: listo ya lo adjunte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando ocurre el `success` de tu ajax, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- En tu id `#carros` (que vendría a ser el `tbody`), buscas el botón <kbd>X</kbd> quien tenga como valor dicho `id` que recibe como parámetro tu función `Eliminar()`:

  ```
  $("#carros").find("button[value='" + id + "']");
  ```
- Luego de encontrar dicho botón, buscamos el elemento `tr` más cercano de ese botón encontrado:

  ```
  $("#carros").find("button[value='" + id + "']").closest("tr");
  ```
- Y por último removemos ese `tr`:

  ```
  $("#carros").find("button[value='" + id + "']").closest("tr").remove();
  ```

De esta forma, eliminas el `tr` correspondiente quien conlleva ese botón <kbd>X</kbd> al quien le diste click.

---

El código del ajax sería:

```
function Eliminar(id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Home/Eliminar?id=' + id,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function () {
      $("#carros").find("button[value='" + id + "']").closest("tr").remove();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Tengo un duda, la fila si se elimina correctamente, a la vista, pero yo tengo un search de datatable, y si vuelvo a buscar ese dato que se "elimino" vuelve aparecer, todavia se tiene que recargar la pagina para que realmente ya no aparezca

Comment: Mmmm tendría que ver cómo está estructurado tu buscador, pero podrías hacer otra pregunta detallando tu nuevo problema, y tendré mayor posibilidad de ayudarte.